# determined vs. determinate (adj.)?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between the adjectival usages of "determined" and "determinate"? Are they interchangeable when used as adjectives?

Comment: What contexts are you trying to use them in? We need examples of a usage. Also, what research have you done and what opinions have you formed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have looked up these two words in a dictionary, you will have noticed that *determined* mostly applies to people while *determinate* is an adjective used primarily to describe nonliving entities such as processes, places, et cetera.

So, if a person is determined to do something, they are hell bent on doing it. If a thing is determinate, that means it is definitive or categorical in a certain way.

Example #1:

> — This type of work requires strength of character and a lot of determination. Not everybody can do it. How **determined** are you to do this job?
>   — Very **determined**!

Example #2:

> Physics has shown that our universe has a **determinate** amount of energy. This amount can't be increased nor decreased. It always stays the same.